# how to do that when i click on the map, the marker disappeared?

Tags: osmdroid

I use asmdroid 4.2 and bonuspack 4.5.

my code add marker:

```
       Marker startMarker = new Marker(mapView);
        startMarker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(locationA,locationB));
        startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(drawable)); 
        startMarker.setTitle("jkdfghspdifj");
        startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, 1.0f);
        MarkerInfoWindow infoWindow = new  MyInfoWindow(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, 
                mapView,title);
        startMarker.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);


 mapView.getOverlays().add(startMarker);

 mapView.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox);

 mapView.invalidate();
```

everything works fine :)

I click on the marker and displayed popup window. and how to do that when you click on the card itself, the marker disappeared? (at the moment it disappears unless again click on it)

Comment: What do you call the "card"? Is it the marker? The popup window? The map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To close all open popups when tapping anywhere on the map, follow the [Tutorial 5](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5), Chapter 16. Handling Map events

To have an open popup that closes when you are opening the popup on an other marker, a simple solution is to share the same infoWindow object between all your markers.

Or call "InfoWindow.closeAllInfoWindowsOn(map);" in onOpen.

Answer (score 0):

paste in my class MarkerInfoWindow
in the metod onOpen

```
public void onOpen(Object arg0) {

    Marker current = (Marker) arg0;
    for(int i=0; i<mMapView.getOverlays().size(); ++i) {
        Overlay o = mMapView.getOverlays().get(i);

        if (o instanceof Marker) {
            Marker m = (Marker) o;
            if(m!=current)
                m.hideInfoWindow();
        }
    }
}
```